# Determine if a line has parenthesis or quotes that are not closed in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Im looking for a simple way to open a file, and search each line to see if that line has unclosed parens and quotes. If the line has unclosed parens/quotes, i want to print that line to a file. I know i could do it with an ugly blob of if/for statements, but i know that python probably has a better way with either the re module (which i know nothing about) or something else but i dont know the language well enough to do so.

Thanks!

Edit: some example lines. May be easier to read if you copy this into notepad or something and turn off word wrap (some lines can be quite long). Also, there are over 100k lines in the file so something efficent would be great!

```
SL  ID=0X14429A0B TY=STANDARD OWN=0X429A03 EXT=22 SLTK=0X1C429A0B MP=0X684003F0 SUB=0X24400007
RT  ID=0X18429A19 TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A0C CMDS=(N:0X8429A04,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=1 DESC="AURANT YD-INDSTRY LD" ATIS=T
RT  ID=0X18429A1A TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A08 CMDS=(R:0X8429A04,N:0X8429A05,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=2 DESC="AURANT YD TO TRK.1" ATIS=T
RT  ID=0X18429A1B TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A0A CMDS=(R:0X8429A04,R:0X8429A05,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=3 DESC="AURANT YD TO TRK.2" ATIS=T
SL  ID=0X14429A0C TY=STANDARD OWN=0X429A03 EXT=24 SLTK=0X1C429A0B MP=0X684003F1 SUB=0X24400007
RT  ID=0X18429A1C TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0C EXLP=0X14429A0B CMDS=(N:0X8429A04,C:0X14429A0C) SGCC=2 REL=1 DESC="AURANT YD-INDSTRY LD" ATIS=T
TK  ID=0X1C429A08 TY=BLKTK OWN=0X429A03 EXT=12 LRMP=0X6C40BDAF LEN=5837 FSPD=60 PSPD=65 QUAL=TRK.1 MAXGE=0 MAXGW=0 JAL=4 ALT=12 SUB=0X24400007 RULES=(CTC:B:UP:0X24400007:485.7305:486.8359:T) LLON=-118.1766772 RLON=-118.1620059 LLAT=34.06838375 RLAT=34.07811764 LELE=416.6983 RELE=425.0596 ULAD=NO URAD=NO
PT  ID=0X20429A0F TY=STANDARD OWN=0X1C429A08 LTK=0X1C40006C RTK=0X1C429A0C REL=1 LEN=1 LQUAL="TRK.1" RQUAL="TRK.1"
PTK OWN=0X1C429A08 PID=0X1C429A13
```

Comment: What do your files contain?  Source code in some programming language?

Comment: Regex alone might fall short here: consider parenthesis inside string literals or comments.

Comment: consider `while (cond){ if (cond2) { }`.  Which is unclosed in your program's opinion, the if or the while?

Comment: @SvenMarnach no its just lines of text. I'll copy some into the body of the op as an example

Comment: Why not use the parser module? It's better than messing around with buggy res that don't capture nested source constructs well.

Comment: should parentheses inside quotes also be balanced?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian as far as i know, there should never be parens in quotes. They used for two separate things in separate place. Should a paren fall between 2 quotes, there is probably a quote error somewhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't think there will be backwards unmatched parens (i.e. ")(") you can do this:

```
with open("myFile.txt","r") as readfile, open("outFile.txt","w") as outfile:
    for line in readfile:
        if line.count("(") != line.count(")") or line.count('"') % 2 != 0:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Otherwise you will have to count them one at a time to check for mismatches, like this:

```
with open("myFile.txt","r") as readfile, open("outFile.txt","w") as outfile:
    for line in readfile:
        count = 0
        for char in line:
            if char == ")":
                count -= 1
            elif char == "(":
                count += 1
            if count < 0:
                break
         if count != 0 or text.count('"') % 2 != 0:
             outfile.write(line)
```

I can't think of any better way to handle it. Python doesn't support recursive regular expressions, so a regular expression solution is right out.

One more thing about this: Given your data, it might be better to put that into a function and split your strings, which is easy to do with a regex, like this:

```
import re
splitre = re.compile(".*?=(.*?)(?:(?=\s*?\S*?=)|(?=\s*$))")
with open("myFile.txt","r") as readfile, open("outFile.txt","w") as outfile:
    for line in readfile:
        def matchParens(text):
            count = 0
            for char in text:
                if char == ")":
                    count -= 1
                elif char == "(":
                    count += 1
                if count < 0:
                    break
            return count != 0 or text.count('"') % 2 != 0
        if any(matchParens(text) for text in splitre.findall(line)):
            outfile.write(line)
```

The reason why that might be better is that it checks each value pair individually, that way if you have an open paren in one value pair and a close paren in a later one, it won't think that there are no unbalanced parens.

Comment: hm yeah your second block may be the way to go. Just counting them may work most of the time but im not sure.

Comment: +1 for not needing any imports. Also for satisfying the "simple" requirement.

Comment: It doesn't ignore `()` inside a quoted string i.e., it treats `"("` as an unbalanced expression. Though @ZakParks mentioned in the comments that it might be treated as an error. The `pyparsing` solution behaves differently.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ignored intentionally for performance and simplicity reasons, as I read his comment as saying that it doesn't happen. The `pyparsing` solution is superior, but `pyparsing` is not in the standard library. This can be considered a "standard library" solution.

Comment: I meant that the behavior of your script might be acceptable (per OPs comments).

Comment: btw, 100K is not much; there is no need for premature optimization.

Comment: there are spaces inside quoted strings so `line.split()` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, changed to a regular expression split. Actually just returns whatever is after each `=`.

Comment: @Josiah A few questions/comments after trying this: Foremost, I get a type error at the `with open()` line, saying "coercing to Unicode: need string of buffer, file found", which I dont know how to handle. Also, is there any benefit to having the function in the block? Im just curious as i've never seen it like that before. Also, I am unsure what the return statement's purpose is in this. I haven't been using python long (~1 month) and this is more advanced code then i've seen haha

Comment: I fixed the type error. Everything works! Although I am still curious about the other questions. Thanks!

Comment: @ZakParks Sorry about the type error, I wrote this code blank page without any testing. If you could tell me what you changed, I can edit my answer to reflect it. There is no benefit to having the function in the instead of outside the block except for readability purposes, if you are worried about performance, move it out of the block. As for the return statement, what happens is I create a generator that runs the function for every value pair, as separated by the regular expression. The function will return True if it finds an unbalanced paren or an unbalanced quote, false otherwise. cont...

Comment: @ZakParks You can imagine the generator as creating a list of the return values that you get when you run matchParens on each value pair, and if any of them return true (i.e. had unbalanced parens or quotes) it will print the line. Because of my implementation choice, instead of making it a list it will stop whenever it finds a true (saving time) but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 5):

It may seem like overkill to use a parser package, but it's pretty quick:

```
text = """\
SL  ID=0X14429A0B TY=STANDARD OWN=0X429A03 EXT=22 SLTK=0X1C429A0B MP=0X684003F0 SUB=0X24400007
RT  ID=0X18429A19 TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A0C CMDS=(N:0X8429A04,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=1 DESC="AURANT YD-INDSTRY LD" ATIS=T
RT  ID=0X18429A1A TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A08 CMDS=(R:0X8429A04,N:0X8429A05,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=2 DESC="AURANT YD TO TRK.1" ATIS=T
RT  ID=0X18429A1B TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A0A CMDS=(R:0X8429A04,R:0X8429A05,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=3 DESC="AURANT YD TO TRK.2" ATIS=T
SL  ID=0X14429A0C TY=STANDARD OWN=0X429A03 EXT=24 SLTK=0X1C429A0B MP=0X684003F1 SUB=0X24400007
RT  ID=0X18429A1C TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0C EXLP=0X14429A0B CMDS=(N:0X8429A04,C:0X14429A0C) SGCC=2 REL=1 DESC="AURANT YD-INDSTRY LD" ATIS=T
TK  ID=0X1C429A08 TY=BLKTK OWN=0X429A03 EXT=12 LRMP=0X6C40BDAF LEN=5837 FSPD=60 PSPD=65 QUAL=TRK.1 MAXGE=0 MAXGW=0 JAL=4 ALT=12 SUB=0X24400007 RULES=(CTC:B:UP:0X24400007:485.7305:486.8359:T) LLON=-118.1766772 RLON=-118.1620059 LLAT=34.06838375 RLAT=34.07811764 LELE=416.6983 RELE=425.0596 ULAD=NO URAD=NO
PT  ID=0X20429A0F TY=STANDARD OWN=0X1C429A08 LTK=0X1C40006C RTK=0X1C429A0C REL=1 LEN=1 LQUAL="TRK.1" RQUAL="TRK.1"
PTK OWN=0X1C429A08 PID=0X1C429A13 GOOD
PTK OWN=0X1C429A(08 PID=0X1C429A13 BAD
PTK OWN=0X1C429A08 )PID=0X1C429A13 BAD
PTK OWN=0X1C(42(9A))08 PID=0X1C429A13 GOOD
PTK OWN=0X1C(42(9A))08 PID=0X1C42(9A13 BAD
PTK OWN=0X1C(42(9A))08 PID=0X1C42"("9A13 GOOD
"""

from pyparsing import nestedExpr, quotedString

paired_exprs = nestedExpr('(',')')  |  quotedString

for i, line in enumerate(text.splitlines(), start=1):
    # use pyparsing expression to strip out properly nested quotes/parentheses
    stripped_line = paired_exprs.suppress().transformString(line)

    # if there are any quotes or parentheses left, they were not 
    # properly nested
    if any(unwanted in stripped_line for unwanted in '()"\''):
        print i, ':', line
```

Prints:

```
10 : PTK OWN=0X1C429A(08 PID=0X1C429A13 BAD
11 : PTK OWN=0X1C429A08 )PID=0X1C429A13 BAD
13 : PTK OWN=0X1C(42(9A))08 PID=0X1C42(9A13 BAD
```

Comment: `pyparsing` seems upto the task. I can't find a counter-example. It correctly treats `"("()` as a balanced expression and `(")""` as an unbalanced one. It is convenient that `ignoreExpr=quotedString` by default for `nestedExpr()`. It treats `"\""` also as balanced i.e., it processes escapes for quoted strings, though `(\()` is treated as unbalanced. It doesn't recognize (as it probably should in this case) Unicode punctuations i.e., `❩“` is treated as balanced.

Comment: Like this solution best by a long shot. And thank you for introducing me to pyparsing :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Just extract all the interesting symbols from a line.
2. Push the opening symbols onto stack and pop from the stack whenever you get a
   closing symbol.
3. If the stack is clean, the symbols are balanced. If
   the stack underflows or doesn't get fully unwound you have unbalanced line.

Sample code for checking a line follows - I've inserted a stray bracket into the first line.

```
d = """SL  ID=0X14429A0B TY=STANDARD OWN=0X429A(03 EXT=22 SLTK=0X1C429A0B MP=0X684003F0 SUB=0X24400007
RT  ID=0X18429A19 TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A0C CMDS=(N:0X8429A04,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=1 DESC="AURANT YD-INDSTRY LD" ATIS=T
RT  ID=0X18429A1A TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A08 CMDS=(R:0X8429A04,N:0X8429A05,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=2 DESC="AURANT YD TO TRK.1" ATIS=T
RT  ID=0X18429A1B TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0B EXLP=0X14429A0A CMDS=(R:0X8429A04,R:0X8429A05,C:0X14429A0B) SGCC=2 REL=3 DESC="AURANT YD TO TRK.2" ATIS=T
SL  ID=0X14429A0C TY=STANDARD OWN=0X429A03 EXT=24 SLTK=0X1C429A0B MP=0X684003F1 SUB=0X24400007
RT  ID=0X18429A1C TY=CALONSC OWN=0X14429A0C EXLP=0X14429A0B CMDS=(N:0X8429A04,C:0X14429A0C) SGCC=2 REL=1 DESC="AURANT YD-INDSTRY LD" ATIS=T
TK  ID=0X1C429A08 TY=BLKTK OWN=0X429A03 EXT=12 LRMP=0X6C40BDAF LEN=5837 FSPD=60 PSPD=65 QUAL=TRK.1 MAXGE=0 MAXGW=0 JAL=4 ALT=12 SUB=0X24400007 RULES=(CTC:B:UP:0X24400007:485.7305:486.8359:T) LLON=-118.1766772 RLON=-118.1620059 LLAT=34.06838375 RLAT=34.07811764 LELE=416.6983 RELE=425.0596 ULAD=NO URAD=NO
PT  ID=0X20429A0F TY=STANDARD OWN=0X1C429A08 LTK=0X1C40006C RTK=0X1C429A0C REL=1 LEN=1 LQUAL="TRK.1" RQUAL="TRK.1"
PTK OWN=0X1C429A08 PID=0X1C429A13"""

def unbalanced(line):
    close_symbols = {'"' : '"', '(': ")", '[': ']', "'" : "'"}
    syms = [x for x in line if x in '\'"[]()']
    stack = []
    for s in syms:
        try:
            if len(stack) > 0 and s == close_symbols[stack[-1]]:
                stack.pop()
            else:
                stack.append(s)
        except: # catches stack underflow or closing symbol lookup
            return True
    return len(stack) != 0


print unbalanced("hello 'there' () []")
print unbalanced("hello 'there\"' () []")
print unbalanced("][")

lines = d.splitlines()  # in your case you can do open("file.txt").readlines()

print [line for line in lines if unbalanced(line)]
```

For large files, you don't want to read all the files into memory so use fragment like this instead:

```
with open("file.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if unbalanced(line):
            print line
```

Comment: So if right parenthesis will occure inside string block it will count as error.

Comment: @Odomontois: the OP indicated in the comments to the question that it might be correct to treat it as an error.

Answer (score 1):

Regex - If you're lines contain no nested parentheses, the solution is pretty straightforward:

```
for line in myFile:
    if re.search(r"\([^\(\)]*($|\()", line):
        #this line contains unbalanced parentheses.
```

If you're working with the possibility of nested statements, it gets a little more complicated:

```
for line in myFile:
    paren_stack = []
    for char in line:
        if char == '(':
            paren_stack.append(char)
        elif char == ')':
            if paren_stack:
                paren_stack.pop()
            else:
                #this line contains unbalanced parentheses.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do something like:

```
for line in open(file, r):
    if line.count('"') % 2 != 0 or line.count('(') != line.count(')'):
        print(line)
```

But I can't be sure that'll suit your needs exactly.

More robust:

```
for line in open(file, r):
    paren_count = 0
    paren_count_start_quote = 0
    quote_open = False
    for char in line:
        if char == ')':
            paren_count -= 1
        elif char == '(':
            paren_count += 1
        elif char == '"':
            quote_open = not quote_open
            if quote_open:
                paren_count_start_quote = paren_count
            elif paren_count != paren_count_start_quote:
                print(line)
                break
        if paren_count < 0:
            break
    if quote_open or paren_count != 0:
        print(line)
```

Didn't test the robust one, should work I think.  It now makes sure things like: ( " ) ", where a set of parens closed inside a quote print the line.

Comment: that may actually work exactly as i need it. I assume the .count() function will auto-parse the whole line? If so that looks to be just what i need

Comment: How do you mean "auto-parse"? It'll take the whole line as a string from the file and run it through the check.  It won't check for weird things like:

blah blah " blah ( blah" )

Comment: Yeah, it does.  To get it to work on a situation like that you'd have to go through character by character and count the openings and closings and break if there are ever more closings than openings.  I was trying to answer with my perceived spirit of the question, rather than the most robust, works for any system ever designed answer.  Why waste time if ())( is guaranteed never to happen?

Comment: @DrGodCarl anything could happen, and if that error isnt caught very bad things could possibly happen ;) Wasting time is no issue of mine.

Comment: Okay, I made it more robust.  It can be improved further, but I don't have time right this instant.

Comment: In your more robust solution, it will print the line twice if there is an unmatched close paren.

Comment: A better fix would be to just get rid of the print within the `if paren_count < 0:` block, then it will break with `paren_count == -1` and print the line in the last if.

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
from tokenize import *
def syntaxCheck(line):
    def readline():
        yield line
        yield ''
    par,quo,dquo = 0,0,0
    count = { '(': (1,0,0),')': (-1,0,0),"'": (0,1,0),'"':(0,0,1) }
    for countPar, countQuo,countDQuo in (
      count.get(token,(0,0))+(token,) for _,token,_,_,_ in tokenize(readline().__next__)):
        par  += countPar
        quo  ^= countQuo
        dquo ^= countDQuo
    return par,quo,dquo
```

note that parentheses inside closed quotes doesnt count, as it counted as single string token.

Answer (score -1):

Should the parens and quotes be closed on each line? If that is the case, you could do a simple count on the parenthesis and quotes. If it's even, they're matched. If it's odd, one is missing. Put that logic in a function, dump the lines of the text file into an array, and call map to execute the function for each string in the array.

My python's rusty, but that's how I would do it assuming everything "should" be on the same line.

Comment: that would be a simple way of doing it. If there isnt another method posted i'll probably go with this. The file im parsing currently has 18 million characters though, so i would think that going line by line, char by char counting parens and quotes could get quite slow though. I'll test it out and see what happens though

Comment: What if the line contains this: `ABC) lsdjfldjsf (`?  There is a matching number of '('s and ')'s, but they aren't properly nested.

Comment: @ZakParks, manually counting characters will be faster than performing regex-matches on the entire input. Besides, 18 million chars is peanuts.

Answer (score -1):

Well my solution may not be as fancy, but I say you just count the number of parenthesis and quotes. If it doesn't come out to an even number, you know you're missing something!